# Send boolean parameter to execute stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I retrieve true or false from checkbox like this:

```
var global = CheckBox1.Checked;
```

then I send it as a parameter for stored procedure like:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@global", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = global;
```

`global` variable returns true or false, depending of selected, but when I use `SqlDbType.Bit` it converts true and false to 1 and 0? so should I receive it in stored procedure like a `boolean` or `varchar`?

Stored procedure:

```
@global as bit

DECLARE @comando as varchar(5000)
SET @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\package.Variables[User::global].Properties[Value]";"\"'+ @global+ '\""'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption here and say that the stored procedure is requiring you to save the variable as datatype bit in the `@comando` variable.

If that's the case, you can leave the stored procedure with `@global` as a bit, and do the following in your code-behind:

```
boolean global = CheckBox1.Checked;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@global", global);
```

or, if you want to maintain the arguably better Add() method instead of the AddWithValue() method, the code that you supplied should work. I am used to VB.net, so syntax may be slightly off, but either should work. When you save the boolean to the parameter `@global` and it is executed, it will be converted to it's equivalent bit value if you do not manually declare it using the Add() method.

[Argument Against Using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

[Potential Duplicate of This Question](http://Passing%20a%20boolean%20type%20into%20a%20bit%20parameter%20type%20in%20C#%20and%20MS%20SQL%20Server)